# How do I find a closest number in Excel and bring back a corresponding cell?

Tags: excel, math, formula

Row 1 :  YORK / LEEDS / WINDSOR / CHESHIRE

Row 2 :   10 /   8    /    6 /    9

So I want to find the closest match to York in the other data across each row, and bring back the title of the closest match.

So the answer i want to bring back for row 2 (York = 10) is "CHESHIRE" as 9 is the closest to 10.

Thank you!

Comment: What if one of the values was 11?

Answer (score 4):

If your data is in `A1:D2` try this "array formula"

`=INDEX(B$1:D$1,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A2-B2:D2)),ABS(A2-B2:D2),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If 2 or more values are equally close then the match will be with the first one from the left.....

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons for avoiding array formulas, see e.g.:

- A [Microsoft page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010228458.aspx) (look for "Disadvantages of using array formulas").
- [This](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/array-formula-heresy).

If you care about this, and prefer not to use array formulas, the following works.

```
=INDEX(B$1:D$1,MATCH(MIN(INDEX(ABS($B2:$D2-$A2),0)),INDEX(ABS($B2:$D2-$A2),0),0))
```

Credits to [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078467/excel-what-determines-evaluation-order-in-a-formula?noredirect=1#comment29913398_20078884) and [barry houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078467/excel-what-determines-evaluation-order-in-a-formula?noredirect=1#comment29913539_20078884), who helped solving [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20078467/2707864).