# Excel: What determines evaluation order in a formula?

Tags: excel, nested, excel-formula

I have a worksheet with the following contents in A1:G1

```
7  8  4  2  9  11  10
```

Formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MIN($B1:$G1-$A1)) (1)
```

evaluates to -5,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS($B1:$G1-$A1)) (2)
```

evaluates to 18. But

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(ABS($B1:$G1-$A1))) (3)
```

gives `#VALUE!`.

To try to understand the issue, I use Formula Auditing -> Evaluate Formula.
In the formulas that work (1 and 2), $A1 is evaluated (underlined) first.
In the formula that doesn't work (3), $B1:$G1 is evaluated (underlined) first.

What is the reason for the error, and the different behavior among formulas?

Comment: I love this question. Looking it up I found this not perfectly satisfying solution - but it might come handy: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/overview-of-formulas-HP010081865.aspx

Comment: For the third formula, I can replicate when the formula is in column A, but if I fill right, I see different results in each cell, which is very odd, since the formula doesn't change.

Comment: @mr.Reband Nice find! Actually, I had originally entered my formula in O1. I will dig here. Still, I find it intriguing that: 1) the order of evaluation is different, 2) filling similarly formula (1) to the right gives a constant result, as opposed to formula (3).

Comment: @Mark : I did not find a hint for a solution in your link. Were you referring to entering the formula as an array (as in the answer by John)?

Comment: @sancho.s Yup, that's why I added a comment and mentioned what I found is not a solution but may give a better understand and can pop new ideas (or not) :)

Comment: @Mark - Point clarified :)

Comment: I actually get `1` rather than `#VALUE` for the third formula (Windows 7, Excel 2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, to get the smallest difference between A1 and B1:G1 without using an "array entered" formula you can use `INDEX` to do what you were trying to do with `SUMPRODUCT`, i.e.

`=MIN(INDEX(ABS($B1:$G1-$A1),0))`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using the `SUMPRODUCT` function to make this formula work as an array formula and that Excel is not calculating your third formula as an array, giving you a `#VALUE` error when the formula is entered in column A. It did not give me this error in the columns B through G, but it also did not calculate as an array. Entering your formula as an array formula by pressing Shift+Ctrl+Enter after typing in your formula will fix this. You can also get the same result using a simpler formula:

```
=MIN(ABS($B1:$G1-$A1))
```

Once this is entered as an array formula, you will be able to step through the evaluation and see it working correctly.

More info on arrays here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I know that entering it as an array formula it works, but I meant to avoid precisely that. This is the reason for introducing `SUMPRODUCT`, and I do not understand why it works only in some cases. The question was aimed specifically at understanding this point, not at alternative ways of arriving at the intended result.

Comment: Nice first answer! +1

Comment: @sancho.s, if that was specifically your point, it was worth mentioning in your question :).

Comment: +1, excellent answer - SUMPRODUCT doesn't always magically convert formulas that require array entry into ones that don't, I assume that ABS needs CSE whatever - TRANSPOSE falls into the same category

Comment: @sancho.s, Your issue is not the evaluation order, but the way Excel is evaluating (array vs. regular function). The solution is to force Excel to evaluate as an array instead of letting it decide how to evaluate by nesting non-array functions inside of an array function (SUMPRODUCT is an array function). It is interesting though how Excel flips the order of evaluations when evaluating as an array vs a regular function. I had never noticed that.

Comment: @John : But then why the different behavior when used with only one of `MIN` or `ABS`, as compared to both? Understanding this may lead to entering the formula suitably, and avoiding an array formula. Would you think that is not possible?

Comment: @barryhoudini : This sort of frames the cause to the kind of input `SUMPRODUCT` takes, but then why the different behavior when used with only one of `MIN` or `ABS`, as compared to both? I still find it strange, as they are nested inside `SUMPRODUCT`. PS: I do not know what CSE means.

Comment: the documentation says the `ABS` takes a number as its input, that `MIN` takes an arbitrary number of numbers, and `SUMPRODUCT` takes an arbitrary number or arrays. Seems like when the ABS is nested so deep it defaults to taking the number and can't figure out how to return an array

Comment: Sorry CSE = CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Can we tag this as part of the Magic of Excel?

Comment: Good point Brad, so to counteract that we can use `INDEX` round ABS and get the correct result without "array entry" and without SUMPRODUCT, i.e. `=MIN(INDEX(ABS($B1:$G1-$A1),0))`

Comment: @barryhoudini : Awesome! This look very much the answer. I would post it as such.

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing the comments by [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078467/excel-what-determines-evaluation-order-in-a-formula?noredirect=1#comment29913398_20078884) and [barry houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079963/2707864) ([originally this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078467/excel-what-determines-evaluation-order-in-a-formula?noredirect=1#comment29913539_20078884)):

The documentation says the `ABS` takes a number as its input, that `MIN` takes an arbitrary number of numbers, and `SUMPRODUCT` takes an arbitrary number or arrays. Seems like when the `ABS` is nested so deep it defaults to taking the number and can't figure out how to return an array.

So to counteract that we can use `INDEX` round `ABS` and get the correct result without "array entry" and without `SUMPRODUCT`, i.e. `=MIN(INDEX(ABS($B1:$G1-$A1),0))`.

This shows the right way of entering the formula, and it explains the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were on course to investigate this using 'Formulas > Evaluate Formula'

The results are for typical math operations: functions are evaluated from the inside out.

Because `=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(ABS($B1:$G1-$A1)))` is not forced to evaluate as an array `$B1:$G1` will return the value from that array from the same column from where the calling cell is located. I.e. if B2 = then `$B1:$G1` will return B1, if A2= `$B1:$G1` then it will try to return A1 but there is nothing to return so it gives you the `#VALUE` error.

Comment: I admit to not fully understanding your answer (I will think about it). In the meantime, do you think it explains the different behavior when used with only one of `MIN` or `ABS`, as compared to both?