# SEARCH function for array of strings rather than single string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's a simple one for any Excel users - I'm currently trying to write a function that will check if a cell contains at least one string out of an array of strings and return a TRUE/FALSE value. My function as it stands looks something like this:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"cat","dog","clog","frog","log","beaver"}, E2)), "og-word", "something else")

The issue with this is that the SEARCH function only checks for the first string in the array rather than checking for all of them. Any quick fixes? Not sure if this would work as I haven't checked yet, but I would rather *not* throw an OR function in there and repeat the SEARCH function multiple times, for cleanliness sake.

Thanks in advance for the responses!

Comment: #1 : http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/601195-check-multiple-text-strings-cell.html

Comment: #2 : http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/07/15/search-for-multiple-text-strings-in-multiple-cells-in-excel-part-2/

Comment: Please post feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in comments [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016478/search-function-for-array-of-strings-rather-than-single-string#comment38901858_25016478) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016478/search-function-for-array-of-strings-rather-than-single-string#comment38901875_25016478), these two work (as I tested)

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(E2,"*"&{"cat","dog","clog","frog","log","beaver"}&"*")),"og-word","something else")

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"cat","dog","clog","frog","log","beaver"},E2))),"og-word","something else")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Sancho! Could you explain why the first one works, i.e. the logic behind it?

Comment: @cjacobso - I would recommend you test yourself the result of each of the nested functions, so you can readily see the effect of each. It is quite instructive!

Comment: @cjacobso - [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20078467/2707864) and its answers are likely relevant. Check in particular [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20080713/2707864).

Answer (score 0):

This will return **True** if *A1* contains either *fat* or *thin:*

```
=NOT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"fat",""),"thin",""))=LEN(A1))
```